# Removing constant artifact/defect from several images

Tags: image-processing

I have several images, each of which has the same artifact/defect. Does anybody have a suggestion to remove such an artifact?

The images are disordered arrays of dots. The artifacts include the 'squiggly worm' and the 'circular ripples' that you can hopefully identify by eye.

I tried using the pixel median of all the images, like in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87901/remove-static-objects-from-an-image-sequence), but I was unsuccessful.

The following code will quickly import all the images.

```
names = 
  {"DgkH6V5", "QHgATwh", "CWMkitU", "IymdBJM", 
   "BxkbVOj", "qyanXWZ", "6Wlvnr1", "upxv4EH"};
frames = Import["https://imgur.com/" <> # <> ".png"] & /@ names;
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have an image with only the artefact and a flat background?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: Consider `ImageAdjust@Mean[EdgeDetect /@ frames]`

Answer (score 3):

For a start, you could consider that your artifacts are of a different frequency than the dots in the background which are slightly blurred:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTMs1.png"];
LowpassFilter[img, .4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Also: `Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTMs1.png"] // HighpassFilter[#, .5] & // ImageAdjust` ... but this is also kind of "tuning" regarding the parameter that makes me a bit uneasy, but so are all somewhat arbitrary constructs that bring out details for a specific set of samples.

Comment: A useful approach. Perhaps I can use the `HighpassFiler` selectively in the regions that contain an artefact, to minimise the image processing done to regions with no defects.

Comment: @Tom That would be a better approach. You weren't clear what you would like to do with the images, but repairing them completely is (a) not possible and (b) nothing you should consider when you want to quantify the data. There are cases in science where you need to *reconstruct* data to quantify it, but in your case, I would also vote to create regions from the artifacts and exclude them.